# PHP:PDO Why this code is not working?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i cant get it why it is not working

```
$q1=$conn->prepare('select * from users where username = :data');
    $q1->bindParam(':data',$searchdata);//$searchdata is having the value
    $q1->execute();

       if($q1->rowCount()<1)
    {
        die('NO results found');
    }
    $row=$q1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo $row['user_id'];
```

The DEBUG DUMP PARAMS RETURNS THIS

```
select * from users where match(username) against(:searchd) Params: 1 Key: Name: [8] :searchd paramno=-1 name=[8] ":searchd" is_param=1 param_type=2
```

Why everytime i am getting empty result? anything wrong in this code. please help.

Comment: What value does `$searchdata` have?

Comment: There could be lots of things wrong, you haven't provided enough information.

Comment: $searchdata is having the value 'akbar'

Comment: From php.net on the method rowCount(): 
"If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications."

Maybe this is the case. What database do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL requires that you use a [buffered query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php), because The `rowCount()` method can't know how many rows there in the result set before all rows have been fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$rowCount = $pdo->query('select count(*) from blah')->fetchColumn(); 

 if(count($rowCount) > 0)
 {
       //Your code here
 } else {
     die();
 }
```